Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined on line: 10
I am trying to solve this challenge.
Question
Given are two arrays a and b, both have three elements. Return a new array of length 2 containing both middle (index 1) elements of the arrays).
Error
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined on line: 10 First Try
Second Try
First try
function goldenMiddle(a, b) {
a = [4,6,2];  // assign an array to a and b 
b = [1,6,8];
var c = []; // created a new array
var resultA = a[1];   // index 1 of array a
var resultB = b[1];  // index 1 of array b 
var newResult = c.push(resultA) + c.push(resultB); // push the resultA and resultB to c
return c;  // return c
}
goldenMiddle()


Second Try
function goldenMiddle(a, b) {
a = []; 
b = [];
var c = []; // created a new array
var resultA = a[1];   // index 1 of array a
var resultB = b[1];  // index 1 of array b 
var newResult = c.push(resultA) + c.push(resultB); // push the resultA and resultB to c
return c;  // return c
}
goldenMiddle(a[1,6,8],  b[4,6,2])


Any idea what the problem might be?
Thanks

Typo?  If you're just trying to pass arrays to the function, just pass arrays: goldenMiddle([1,6,8], [4,6,2])  The identifiers a and b don't really make sense where you're using them on that line, given the rest of the code.

Why assign a twice with two different values? A variable can only have one value.

also goldenMiddle(a[1,6,8],  b[4,6,2]) is pretty wrong, I'm not sure what you mean by that but it's not correct.

@Pointy OP seems to just severely misunderstand parameters.

In both tries, you're only using the parameter a and not b.
By using a = [], you are clearing the array.
Also, you dont need to put parameter name in the arguments, arrays are directly passed as parameters simply just using [].
Your code can be simply like this:
function goldenMiddle(a, b) {
    return [a[1], b[1]];
}

goldenMiddle([1, 6, 8], [4, 6, 2]);


Thank you very much for the idea, It worked and was straightforward.

enter image description hereFor your error, you must call goldenMiddle like this
function goldenMiddle(a, b) {
  a = []; 
  a = [];
  var c = []; // created a new array
  var resultA = a[1];   // index 1 of array a
  var resultB = a[1];  // index 1 of array b 
  var newResult = c.push(resultA) + c.push(resultB); // push the resultA and resultB to c
  return c;  // return c
}
goldenMiddle([1,6,8],  [4,6,2]) // remove the a and b from this line

However, to accomplish your function, there are a couple other things you need to adjust
function goldenMiddle(a, b) {
  // a = []; Comment these lines, if you don't a will be set to an empty array
  // a = [];
  var c = []; // created a new array
  var resultA = a[1];   // index 1 of array a
  var resultB = b[1];  // index 1 of array b (change from 'a' to 'b')
  c.push(resultA); // These need to be independent
  c.push(resultB); // push the resultA and resultB to c
  return c;  // return c
}
console.log(goldenMiddle([1,6,8],  [4,6,2])) // remove the a and b from this line and print it

